# Куда кидать файл при исполнении приложения в eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, java, linux

Отрывок из кода

```
Document doc = (Document) builder.parse("strings.xml");
```

Куда этот файл положить, чтоб при нажатии кнопочки [image] файл был виден

Os - linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В workspace в папку с приложением. Вернее в папку bin в свой пакет если class там!

Answer (score 0):

А еще можно,полный путь для надежности прописать,ведь вы в линуксе просто на файл *копировать*,вот вам и путь уже,но в java встроена такая фишка:

**String path = file.getAbsolutePath();**

получаем путь абсолютный,удобно)